# Reading data from Blazor component

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor, so this will seem like an elementary problem to solve. I have a simple Blazor component that is just a text box and a button that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control input-user" 
    tabindex="1" @ref="UsernameControl" @bind-value="UserName" placeholder="Username...">
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn login-btn" 
    tabindex="3" @onclick="OnLoginButtonClick">Login</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnLoginButtonClick { get; set; }
    private ElementReference UsernameControl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a parent control that uses this control, like this:

```
<UserBox OnLoginButtonClick="@LoginButtonClicked" />

@code {
    private void LoginButtonClicked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked! ");
        Console.WriteLine(UserName); // This line doesn't work, obviously
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get the text that was entered in the text box. Obviously the line I posted above is not going to work. How do I get the value from the text box from my parent control? I am using `@bind-value` which should populate it in the `UserName` property, so I am sure the data is stored there, but I am not sure how to get it from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it as an argument to the login button clicked method for example:

```
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn login-btn" tabindex="3" 
  @onclick="(() => OnLoginButtonClick(UserName))">Login</button>


private void LoginButtonClicked(string userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `EventCallback` to an `EventCallback<string>`, then you can invoke it with a string value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

parent component

```html
<UserBox OnLoginButtonClick="@LoginButtonClicked" />

@code {

    private void LoginButtonClicked(string UserName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked! ");
        Console.WriteLine(UserName); // This line doesn't work, obviously
    }
}
```

and you parent

```html
<input type="text" name="" class="form-control input-user" 
    tabindex="1" @ref="UsernameControl" @bind-value="UserName" placeholder="Username...">
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn login-btn" 
    tabindex="3" @onclick="Login">Login</button>

@code {
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> OnLoginButtonClick { get; set; }
    private ElementReference UsernameControl { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    
    public async Task Login()
    {
    await OnLoginButtonClick.InvokeAsync(UserName);
    }
}
```